# How can I select only the top part of a cylinder?

Tags: modeling, selection-tools

If I press <kbd>A</kbd> it will select the whole object in edit mode.
But I need to to select only the top part, like in this picture.

This is a screenshot showing what I need to select:
[image: cylinder top selected]

And this is what happen when I try to select it:
[image: cylinder all selected]

Comment: How did you get the first screenshot and how does that differ from what you want to do?

Comment: Use a border selection tools (*B* or *C* shortcut) to select them.

Comment: Switch to face mode (Ctrl + Tab), select the face (right-click), then switch back to vertex mode (Ctrl + Tab).

Comment: @Mr Zak I guess he's following a tutorial or something: the two objects are similar but not equal...